# How to add a request parameter using javascript in jsp file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc, attributes

I have this code in my jsp :

```
....
<td>                                
 <select name="role" id="role">
 <option selected></option>
 <option value="ROLE_USER">ROLE_USER</option>
 <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">ROLE_ADMIN</option>
 <option value="ROLE_BDDADMIN">ROLE_BDDADMIN</option>
 </select>                      
</td>
....
```

This code isn't included in `form` tag.
What I want to do is to find a way to transfer a selected value to the server, knowing that there isn't a `form` tag.

I choose to use a javascript function to put the selected value as a request parameter like this :

```
<a  href="<c:url value="/admin/addRole?role="/>" onclick="document.getElementById("role").attributes["name"].value;">
 Add
</a>
```

But this doesn't work.

I'm using Spring MVC, if there is another way than using javascript.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried it using AJAX !! it gonna solve the problem immediatly

Comment: I will try. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: If there is any trouble with it let me know !!

Comment: Do you use some stuff like jQuery?

Comment: No, until now I never use neither AJAX nor JQuery. I'll stop the development for a while to learn them. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works but I'm not completely satisfied. I didn't use AJAX because from what I understood during my learning of AJAX's principe, it is specially used to retrieve data from the server. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Here my solution :

```
<a id="link" href="<c:url value="/admin/addRole"/>">Add</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){      
        jQuery("#role").change(function(){
          var id=${ listeInscrit.id_inscription };//this is a request attribut
          var role = jQuery('#role').find(":selected").val(); 
          jQuery("#link").attr("href",'<c:url value="/admin/adduser?id='+id+'&role='+role+'"/>');
      });               
    });
</script>
```

I am not satisfied because I have a table with several rows of users, each user should have a role and this solution works only for the first row.